# Visula studio 2013 unable to debug in debug mode

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, xamarin

Hi one of my Xamarin project, which was working perfectly till now, has a problem. Even when I run the application in debug mode I am unable to debug the code. It installs as in release mode.

Any solution for this issue.

Comment: what are the exact symptoms you have? Does it not stop at debug points?

Comment: Yes it will not. I am debugging using Android phone. Till yesterday I could able to debug perfectly.

Comment: I think that's the second question with similar issue today, is there any new updates installed ?

Comment: Have you tried, restarting Visual Studio, Deleting the bin folder, Removing the app from the phone and finally if still no success (yeah I know it sounds odd..) restarted your computer?

Comment: Yes Mark. But I am so sorry for this, I got this working. There was the project configuration property set to Bundle Assemblies Into Native code to True. Once I made it false i got to debug again. I am not sure if this is a default behaviour?

Comment: that is a odd behavior indeed and not standard as far as I know.. But good that you brought it up and running again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a project configuration property set to Bundle Assemblies Into Native code to True. Once I made it false i got to debug again